# How to implement breakpoints in Lua using the standard hooks?

Tags: debugging, lua, hook, breakpoints

This question is motivated by Exercise 25.7 on p. 264 of *Programming in Lua* (4th ed.), and more specifically, the optimization proposed in the hint (I've emphasized it in the quote below):

> **Exercise 25.7:** Write a library for breakpoints.  It should offer at least two functions
>
> `setbreakpoint(function, line)      --> returns handle`
>
> `removebreakpoint(handle)`
>
> We specify a breakpoint by a function and a line inside that function.  When the program hits a breakpoint, the library should call `debug.debug`.  (Hint: for a basic implementation, use a line hook that checks whether it is in a breakpoint; to improve performance, **use a call hook to trace program execution and only turn on the line hook when the program is running the target function**.)

I can't figure out how to implement the optimization described in the hint.

Consider the following code (this is, of course, an artificial example concocted only for the sake of this question):

```
 function tweedledum ()
   while true do
     local ticket = math.random(1000)
     if ticket % 5  == 0 then tweedledee() end
     if ticket % 17 == 0 then break end
   end
 end

 function tweedledee ()
   while true do
     local ticket = math.random(1000)
     if ticket % 5  == 0 then tweedledum() end
     if ticket % 17 == 0 then break end
   end
 end

 function main ()
   tweedledum()
 end
```

Function `main` is supposed to represent the program's entrypoint.  Functions `tweedledum` and `tweedledee` are almost identical to each other, and do little more than invoke each other repeatedly.

Suppose I set a breakpoint on `tweedledum`'s assignment line.  I can implement a call hook can check whether `tweedledum` has been invoked, and then sets a line hook that will check when the desired line is being invoked<sup>1</sup>.

More likely than not, `tweedledum` will invoke `tweedledee` before it breaks out of its loop.  Suppose that this happens.  The currently enabled line hook can detect that it is no longer in `tweedledum`, and re-install the call hook.

At this point the execution can switch from `tweedledee` to `tweedledum` in one of two ways:

1. `tweedledee` can invoke `tweedledum` (yet again);
2. `tweedledee` can *return* to its invoker, which happens to be `tweedledum`.

*And here's the problem:* the call hook can detect the event in (1) but it cannot detect the event in (2).

Granted, this example is very artificial, but it's the simplest way I could come up with to illustrate the problem.

The best approach I can think of (and it's very weak!) is to keep track of the stack depth `N` at the *first* invokation of `tweedledum`, have the line hook reinstall the call hook only when the stack depth sinks below `N`.  Thus, the line hook will be in force as long as `tweedledee` is in the stack, whether it is being executed or not.

Is it possible to implement the optimization described in the hint using only the standard hooks available in Lua?<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> My understanding is that, by installing the line hook, the call hook essentially uninstalls itself.  AFAICT, only one hook can be active per coroutine.  ***Please do correct me if I am wrong.***</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Namely: call, line, return, and count hooks.</sup>

Comment: By the way, since I see you asking lots of Lua-related questions here, it might be worth mentioning that there's an (unofficial) Lua discord server. See: this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/lua/comments/b7fsk7/lua_discord_server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And here's the problem: the call hook can detect the event in (1) but it cannot detect the event in (2).

And that's where you're wrong: There's three possible hook events: `l` for line, `c` for call and `r` for return.

Inside your hook function you can treat *return* and *call* events as almost the same, except when the `return` event is fired, you're still inside the called function, so the target function is one place higher in the stack.

```lua
debug.sethook(function(event, line)
   if event == "call" or event == "return" then
      if debug.getinfo(event=='call' and 2 or 3).func == target then
         debug.sethook(debug.gethook(), 'crl')
      else
         debug.sethook(debug.gethook(), 'cr')
      end
   elseif event == 'line' then
      -- Check if the line is right and possibly call debug.debug() here
   end
end, 'cr')
```

It's all in the [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-debug.sethook) ;)

---

Note that, when setting the hook, you may need to check if you're currently *inside* the target function; otherwise you may skip a break point unless you call (and return from) another function before reaching it.

Comment: Thank you.  As a beginner, I find the manual nearly useless: it is written for people who already understand the concepts it describes, so it may be useful as a reference, but not as way to learn the stuff.  Not to me, anyway.  The only way I have been able to figure out what some the things the manual says mean is by experimentation.  And a lot of it.  For example, that's how I found that only one hook can be active at a time.  Your post is the first time I saw that one can combine the indicators 'l', 'c', and 'r'.  Again, it's obvious if you already know it, but not otherwise.

Comment: "The string mask may have any combination of the following characters, with the given meaning" Again, it's all in the manual ;) But yeah, it's a reference, not a guide. Programming in Lua is exactly the right resource for first learning the language but I strongly recommend getting used to the reference anyway; it's very complete, but you have to pay attention to every word.

Comment: Yeah, after I read your post, I went back and saw that.  I had read right over the first time around.  Here's why: in all the examples of `sethook` in PIL, the author never uses more than one character for this parameter, which primes one to think this is a 1-character parameter.

Comment: **Q:** what would happen if you replaced the `elseif event == 'line'` with plain `else`?

Comment: **A:** nothing in your example, I just think it makes it clear what the "else" is. Also there's the possibility for a "count" event, so it's more future-proof with the explicit `elseif`.